# Android Studio error:- E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle'

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.kushalpc.app1;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText userNameEditText;
    EditText passwordEditText;
    TextView userNameTextView;
    TextView passwordTextView;
    TextView resultTextView;
    CharSequence resultLoginSuccess = "Login Successful";
    CharSequence resultLoginFailed = "Login Failed";
    TextView createAccount;
    Button loginButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        userNameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userName);
        passwordTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);
        userNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNameValue);
        passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordValue);
        resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        createAccount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.createAccountTextView);
        createAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setContentView(R.layout.registration);
            }
        });
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(userNameEditText.getText().toString().equals("admin")
                        && passwordEditText.getText().toString().equals("1234"))
                    resultTextView.setText(resultLoginSuccess);
                else
                    resultTextView.setText(resultLoginFailed);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my RegistrationForm.java file

```
package com.example.kushalpc.app1;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class RegistrationForm extends AppCompatActivity{
    Button goButton;
    TextView errorTextView;
    CharSequence c = "HEY";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration);
        goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goButton);
        errorTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emptyErrorTextView);
        goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println(c);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ActivityMain.xml

```
    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/userName"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/userNameValue"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/userName"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/passwordValue"
        android:layout_below="@id/userName"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/password"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        />
    <TextView

        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/password"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@id/userName"
        android:id="@id/password"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/passwordValue"
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />

    <TextView

        android:text="@string/createAccount"
        android:id="@+id/createAccountTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@id/loginButton"
        android:clickable="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/resultTextView"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@id/password"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Registration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    tools:Context="com.example.kushalpc.app1.RegistrationForm">

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/name"

        />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lastName"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/lastName"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/dateOfBirth"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/dateOfBirth"
        android:layout_below="@id/lastName"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/createPassword"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/createPassword"
        android:layout_below="@id/dateOfBirth"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/conformPassword"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/conformPassword"
        android:layout_below="@id/createPassword"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/createUserName"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/createUserName"
        android:layout_below="@id/conformPassword"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nameValue"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lastNameValue"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dateOfBirthValue"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@id/lastName"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/createPasswordValue"

        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        android:layout_below="@id/dateOfBirth"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/conformPasswordValue"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@id/createPassword"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/createUserNameValue"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@id/conformPassword"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/createUserNameValue"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/createUserNameValue"
        android:id="@+id/goButton"
        android:text="@string/go"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        />
    <!--

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/createUserName"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/createUserName"
            android:id="@+id/exitButton"
            android:text="@string/exit"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            />-->


    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/goButton"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="sample"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/emptyErrorTextView"
        />
        <!--android:layout_below="@id/exitButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run my code following are log cat error in red:

> - 07-08 11:44:38.704 1578-1578/com.example.kushalpc.app1 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from
>     method com.example.kushalpc.app1.MainActivity.access$super
> - 07-08 11:44:38.704 1578-1578/com.example.kushalpc.app1 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from
>     method com.example.kushalpc.app1.MainActivity.access$super
>
> -07-08 11:44:38.704 1578-1578/com.example.kushalpc.app1 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController',
>   referenced from method
>   com.example.kushalpc.app1.MainActivity.access$super
>
> -07-08 11:44:38.712 1578-1578/com.example.kushalpc.app1 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method
>   com.example.kushalpc.app1.MainActivity.access$super
>
> -07-08 11:44:38.712 1578-1578/com.example.kushalpc.app1 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method > com.example.kushalpc.app1.MainActivity.access$super
>
> -07-08 11:44:38.720 1578-1578/com.example.kushalpc.app1 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced
>   from method com.example.kushalpc.app1.MainActivity.access$super
>
> -07-08 11:44:38.720 1578-1578/com.example.kushalpc.app1 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from
>   method com.example.kushalpc.app1.MainActivity.access$super
>
> -07-08 11:44:38.720 1578-1578/com.example.kushalpc.app1 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method >com.example.kushalpc.app1.MainActivity.access$super
>
> -07-08 11:44:38.736 1578-1578/com.example.kushalpc.app1 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method 
>   com.example.kushalpc.app1.MainActivity.access$super
>
> -07-08 11:44:38.736 1578-1578/com.example.kushalpc.app1 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method 
>   com.example.kushalpc.app1.MainActivity.access$super
>
> -07-08 11:44:38.744 1578-1578/com.example.kushalpc.app1 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method 
>   com.example.kushalpc.app1.MainActivity.access$super
>
> -07-08 11:44:47.180 1578-1578/com.example.kushalpc.app1 E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache 07-08
>   11:44:47.188 1578-1578/com.example.kushalpc.app1 E/OpenGLRenderer:
>   MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192 07-08 11:44:47.244
>   1578-1578/com.example.kushalpc.app1 E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting
>   MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints() 07-08 11:44:47.244
>   1578-1578/com.example.kushalpc.app1 E/OpenGLRenderer:
>   MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
>
> -07-08 11:44:47.336 1578-1578/com.example.kushalpc.app1 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable',
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
>
> - 07-08 11:49:31.865 5587-5587/com.example.kushalpc.app1 E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache 07-08
>     11:49:31.869 5587-5587/com.example.kushalpc.app1 E/OpenGLRenderer:
>     MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192 07-08 11:49:31.885
>     5587-5587/com.example.kushalpc.app1 E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting
>     MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints() 07-08 11:49:31.893
>     5587-5587/com.example.kushalpc.app1 E/OpenGLRenderer:
>     MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
>
> -07-08 11:49:31.917 5587-5587/com.example.kushalpc.app1 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable',
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering

Comment: None of those are problems. They are perfectly normal, when your code (or code from libraries) refers to classes or methods that do not exist on the device.

Comment: How do I fix it?  I'm using geny motion google nexus 5 - 4.4.4- API 19

Comment: There is nothing wrong, based solely on those messages. Hence, there is nothing to fix.

Comment: gobutton onclicklistener is not working!

Comment: @CommonsWare  gobutton onclicklistener is not working!

Comment: That may be true, but that has nothing to do with those messages. You may wish to switch to `Log.d()` or something instead of `System.out.println()`.

Answer (score 1):

just add multiDexEnabled true in your build.gradle(Module: app) file defaultConfig section and rebuild projects. it will remove all the errors but you would not use instant run below 21.

example is below

> in build.gradle(Module: app) 
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   defaultConfig {
>           ......
>           multiDexEnabled true
>           }
>   .
>   .
>   .